# Jetpack Compose. How to change the background color when holding your finger on the card element

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

if in the color property we can only change the color of the container and content, while we can change the elevation under a variety of conditions???

I didn't find the right property for any of the elements, but I really need it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If an answer resolved your issue, you can accept that answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`combinedClickable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).combinedClickable(androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.Indication,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0)) Modifier:

> Configure component to receive clicks, double clicks and long clicks via input or accessibility "click" event. 
> Add this modifier to the element to make it clickable within its bounds.

You can try to use it as follows and report back if it works:

```
var cardColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Gray) }

Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = 180.dp, height = 100.dp)
        .combinedClickable(
            onClick = { },
            onLongClick = { cardColor = Color.Red },  // change color
        ),
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = cardColor
    )
) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Long-press me", Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    }
}
```

This will make your Card background be gray in the beginning, and after a long press, it will switch to red.